# Retrieving a table row data using selenium python web driver

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with bunch of rows in angular grid style. My requirement is to fetch a specific table row along with its data based on some condition using selenium webdriver for python. I'm familiar with retrieving plain html table data in selenium but I have no clue on how to do this for angular grid based tables. Can someone give me directions to get this one. Here is the table that I'm working on:

```
<div class="ag-body-viewport-wrapper" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<div class="ag-body-viewport">
<div class="ag-body-container" style="width: 1117px; height: 5291px;">
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ng-scope" style="top: 333px; height: 37px; width: 1117px;" row="9" v_element_id="342">
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-0 ag-cell-value" style="width: 225px;" tabindex="-1" col="0" v_element_id="343">satsite1447401448</div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-1 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="1" v_element_id="344"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-2 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="2" v_element_id="345"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-3 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="3" v_element_id="346"></div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-4 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="4" v_element_id="347"> </div>
</div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ng-scope" style="top: 370px; height: 37px; width: 1117px;" row="10" v_element_id="348">
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-0 ag-cell-value" style="width: 225px;" tabindex="-1" col="0" v_element_id="349">satsite1447401948</div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-1 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="1" v_element_id="350"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-2 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="2" v_element_id="351"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-3 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="3" v_element_id="352"></div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-4 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="4" v_element_id="353"> </div>
</div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ng-scope" style="top: 407px; height: 37px; width: 1117px;" row="11" v_element_id="354">
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-0 ag-cell-value" style="width: 225px;" tabindex="-1" col="0" v_element_id="355">satsite1447462846</div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-1 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="1" v_element_id="356"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-2 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="2" v_element_id="357"> </div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-3 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="3" v_element_id="358"></div>
<div class="ag-cell ag-cell-no-focus cell-col-4 ag-cell-value" style="width: 223px;" tabindex="-1" col="4" v_element_id="359"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use a selector for `.ag-row` and `.ag-cell` the same way you might use a selector for `tr` and `td` for an HTML table.

Comment: Could you please share some reference code snippet to retrieve the row, column count and text for each column.